# How to make a simple timer image slideshow using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, jquery-ui, animate.css

I'm trying to make a simple timer slideshow, where an image is only visible for a certain amount of time (5 seconds) and then the sliedshow goes to another image - this repeats forever.

I've searched for a solution, but can't seem to get anything to work right.
Any help would be amazing, thank you beforehand.

Here's what I've tried so far - two images fading in, but they do not overlap. One is above the other, the fading animation works, but they both fade at the exact same time instead of one fading and transitioning to the next image.

```css
@keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
    0% { opacity:1; }
   45% { opacity:1; }
   55% { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}

#cf {
  animation-name            : cf3FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function : ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  animation-duration        : 10s;
  animation-direction       : alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="12289696_1526730367649084_3157113004361281453_n.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="11406788_1433347623654026_6824927253890240539_n.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at CSS animation

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: KrisD I edited my question and put the code I was trying to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with 2 image , you can do something at low cost with CSS animation:

```css
@keyframes cf {
  50% {/* at 50%, it avoids alternate mode */
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#cf {/* same size as image */
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  margin:auto;
}

#cf img {
  position: absolute;/* lets stack them */
}

#cf .top {
  animation: cf 10s infinite; /* let it run for ever */
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/3" />
  <img class="top" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, I would have to use a http source image? I'm creating my own website, and using my local images for an img src is not working.

Comment: That was a stupid question. I apologize I had a blond moment XD

But thank you, this worked just as i wanted!
Although one last question. For the position you put absolute, and the animation works fine.
What if i want the images at the center of the webpage? Instead of on the right

Comment: @JaoJao the container #cf is in the flow, margin:auto will do ;) horizontally, else, flex can , at low cost too, center X,Y this box : example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMxgOW

Comment: I'm using Firefox. I'm not sure if that's a problem because it's not auto aligning to the page ;-;. Still to the far right. (using same image dimensions)

Comment: @JaoJao what code are you trying ? do you have a link ? i use FF by defaut too

Comment: The code you put. I just used my own images instead of the images you provided.
But here's the link of the whole project. Images wont show of course.
https://jsfiddle.net/cb7cy2hp/

Comment: @JaoJao i put white borders, it seems centered to me (fixed the center and font tag too ) https://jsfiddle.net/cb7cy2hp/2/

Comment: I found a way to upload a screenshot of what I'm getting
To be honest I'm not even sure why it's doing this
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24llvd3&s=9#.VplyTlnL_1U

Comment: @JaoJao it is probably your tag <center> or text-align:center playing around with absolute. add text-align:left to #cf

Comment: I took out the centers and added text-align: left. The absolute moved to the left just a little bit. It's not necessarily center, or left. Still a bit on the right
Now that I think of it, it may be my other CSS script causing the issue
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=25ukx1v&s=9#.Vpl0kFnL_1U

Comment: @JaoJao difficult to guess, maybe something floatting in the way, or some other margin ,padding or transform set somewhere else

Comment: I'm going to spend some time debugging this. But thank you so much! You were an amazing help. Your code helped immensely. Now to find out this bug XD
Thank you sir! I wish i could move this answer up, but I'm not 15rep yet ;-;.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML and CSS (without `javascript`) may be used animation css3 property.
For example for 3 slides:
HTML and CSS - first are declared `img` for loading (for smooth animation)

```css
    body{
      background:no-repeat;
      -webkit-animation:animation 10s infinite;
      -moz-animation:animation 10s infinite;
      animation:animation 10s infinite;   
      -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
      -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
      animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    .for_load{
      width:1px;
      height:1px;
      position:absolute;
      left:-1px;
      top:-1Px;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animation{
      0%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      30%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      33%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      63%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      66%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      97%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      100%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animation{
      0%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      30%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      33%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      63%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      66%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      97%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      100%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
    }
    @keyframes animation{
      0%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      30%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
      33%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      63%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/201/);
      }
      66%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      97%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/202/);
      }
      100%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
      }
    }
```

```html
<img class="for_load" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
    <img class="for_load" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/201/">
    <img class="for_load" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/202/">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/muLgodbf/

Comment: background-image + animation never worked so far in firefox. you should use background position (multiple backgound of course) ;) , beside, if this is content , it should stand in html not bg .  op did not say :) for a bg, it could be a sprite run via steps()

Comment: Do you mind if i ask what's the difference between the three keyframes declerations? I just thought that @keyframes was the general rule for CSS3 animations. What's the moz and web-kit keyframes?

Comment: @JaoJao these use to be vendor prefix needed for older versions, there are not needed anymore nowdays, you may not mind them